# Are there some topics that are too sensitive to discuss on the main site?

Tags: discussion

I am on History SE, where two of the most frequent topics are the Holocaust (and related issues) and the (American) Civil War (and I'm not referring to the battles.)

I am thinking of asking a question on this site about how to introduce/present such topics. Would they be too sensitive for a site like this?

Yes, I have chosen two of the most "hot button" issues for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Related: https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1303/how-to-handle-touchy-subjects

Comment: Can you give an example of the question you wish to ask? It's really difficult to address this sort of thing without better understanding of the question and how it relates to IPS.

Comment: That's... not an example. Do you mean something like "How do I confront my anti-semitic grandfather to let him know I'm marrying a Jewish woman"?

Comment: @Catija: A (Jewish) professor once told me, "You're the one guy I know that will stand on a soapbox and tell the world that you see another Holocaust coming,...If that's what you honestly believe." The general question was "when is the truth (or an honestly held belief), too bad too tell?"

Comment: "the truth" and "an honestly held belief" are two completely different things. Your example could not be classified as truth, other than the fact that someone said what they believed. How about linking some actual History SE questions, so the impact there can be understood?

Answer (score 3):

I think that as long as you're within the bounds of the [Be Nice Policy](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice), and you're not crossing into [**N**ot **S**afe **F**or **W**ork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_safe_for_work) territory you should be relatively OK.

We've already had a few questions that touched on sensitive subjects like gender issues, race, religion, and veganism. As long as you can approach the subject in a respectful way, I don't see a problem. Honestly I hope to see more of these kinds of questions because they tend to be areas where people need to exercise their interpersonal skills the most and they tend to draw useful answers.

Comment: I would add that if we do talk about sensitive topics, then I would ask that all users do flag things as they see fit. The last thing I'd like to see is to see arguments that divide users and the community.

Answer (score 2):

Any topic that has an interpersonal component ought not to be 'too sensitive' on Interpersonal.SE -- and moreover, your question is not apparently about any sensitive topic itself, but mainly about *'how to bring up and discuss sensitive topics **like these**'* so I see no problem with posting this type of question on the main site. Again, simply mentioning topics like racism can create sharp responses from multiple users, but I am sure you will present things with due respect and the moderators will efficiently **moderate** the discussion!

Comment: Have to say I like this answer.  With respect to IP ... people post sensitive topic questions because *they have a problem and they want advice*.  They are not simply abstract "hot button issues", they are also personal issues causing real anxiety to real people.  It's worth some extra attention trying to keep people civil, in hopes that there will emerge some answer useful to OP.  You can make a similar argument for history; these things *happened*, so they are appropriate for historians to chew on.

Comment: Yes indeed @akaioi -- sensitive issues need to be discussed, *but sensitively* -- it is the duty of the community to exercise moderation and self-control in answers and comments, which they have been doing well recently, helped by the tireless efforts of the moderators.